# Altium - Cannot Select/highlight components on PCB

Tags: components, altium, component-selection

this issue arises out of no where periodically. Very frustrated!!

Suddenly I am unable to select any component on the PCB board in order to move it/right-click (the grey box doesn't appear).

I have tried selecting a box around the component but it does not highlight it. 
I cannot even right click to see properties.
It is as if the component is gone

I can however, with 'cross select mode' in tools enabled, select the component in the schematic, come back into my pcb design and click 'reposition selected components', however once the component is placed i cannot then click back onto it to adjust or do anything.

After it happens i close it down, go back to an earlier save that i know was working fine, and the problem persists.

Can anybody think of any reason why it would do this??

maybe i have clicked a keyboard shortcut by accident?

Comment: Maybe you accidentally set the "locked" property to true?

Comment: Thanks, do you know how this could have been done?

Comment: I have used 'Edit>Select>All locked' but nothing is selected. 
Even when I use 'Edit>Select>All on Layer' which should work as far as I know, but still no components are selected.

Comment: Also, when I go into the internal plane layer, I should be able to double click and bring up the options of which signal i want the plane, but no options appear, seems to be connected to the same issue. Spending many hours trying to resolve this with no luck... any help much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you somehow re-assigned the left mouse key or something weird like that? Can you move a component when you select it using the side panel and then use the arrow keys?

Comment: No I can't, but i can get into the properties that way.
The reason I don't think the left mouse button is the issue is that i can select signal tracks as normal, I can even select the primitives as normal, its only the whole component which wont select, very strange

Comment: *I do however have a workaround for each issue now if anyone else is interested... 
-To move I have 'tools>Cross Select Mode' checked and select the component in the schematic then use 'Tools>Component Placement>Reposition Selected Components' 
-To access component properties as Rev1.0 mensioned above :) 
-To change the internal split plane 'PCB>Split Plane Editor Select the net/layer and double click the net to bring up properties. 
Hope this helps someone else in the same position!

Comment: Check your selection filter.
I faced the same problem, later found that selection filter was set to "tracks"

Answer (score 7):

You must make sure that the Components (or All Objects) object is selected inside the Properties panel in the PCB editor. You cannot use the mouse to click and select objects in the editor that are deselected in the selection filter. It's a feature you'll probably want to keep pinned to the sidebar.

Answer (score 4):

Nearly lost my mind over this myself...

Check selection filter in properties tab! In Altium 18 this is after the search field

Answer (score 4):

I was having this same exact issue on Altium 21. Press "Shift+C" to clear filter. Or right click and use the click the "Clear filter" option.  The issue would arise when I would search for a reference designator in the search bar or use the cross probe tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you click the clear button you should be able to select again. I had it also a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Even after checking the selection filter(s), I was unable to select a polygon (also, the polygon manager said the polygon was not modified, and not locked). I needed to right-click->Polygon Manager & then click Repour...->Force Repour All Polygons, which seemed to make the polygon selectable again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is very frustrating. There is a deep bug in Altium. Some times it helps to set all components to locked, and then back to unlocked. But last time the solution was to select all components. Then move them a bit, and then selecting undo so all moved back to their original position. After this, all components could be selected as usual.

The chalenge is of cause to select the components when they can not be selected. For me the select touching rectangle (drag left) was working, even if the selection was not highlighted.

Retrying this on another version of the same pcb, with the same problem did not work.
I have even tried Altium 19 and 17 without any success.

Comment: Altium also seems to have all sorts of rendering bugs. Last week some auto-routed tracks were not visually making contact between pads. Closing and reopening the files did solve the problem, however.

Answer (score 0):

I know how to solve this problem!!!
Using Ctrl+A ,whatever happened ,then drag all things on your screen  several times and you will find the components are all selected/highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but it may help other.

I was using a pad as a mouse and it happened to me too. I disconnected it and used a regular mouse which solved the pb.

Answer (score 0):

Old post.. had same issue.

Deleted in schematic... updated PCB so it got removed... then undid remove in schematic and could place it back....

Thinking of it, I was playing with rules and it came back with rule conflict. Maybe it is caused by an 'DRC error'.

Next time I will try to switch of DRC and have a go again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with polygons. I couldn't select it to edit its vertices. The way I found to select the polygon and edit its shape is **SHIFT+LEFT CLICK** on the polygon.